# Input impedance for analog signal

Tags: analog, impedance

"The minimum specification for input impedance is the static input resistance and, if significant, the input capacitance, inductance, and leakage current."

(Chapter 7.1, pg.43 IEEE std 1241-2010)

What is the relation leakage current and input impedance? Is it important for input impedance?

Answer (score 1):

The input current into a device is comprised of a number of terms, including current proportional to the static input resistance according to Ohm's law, and several other leakage terms which are not linearly proportional to input voltage, such as MOS gate-oxide leakage.

Leakage terms do not directly determine the static input resistance, but as the IEEE standard states, they are important to specify if they are significant. If the port of an ADC has an input impedance of 10 GOhm, you may assume that you could drive it with a 10 Mohm source. But if it has even a few nA of input leakage, you will be surprised by the error in the result.